# Problems designing Bejeweled game

Tags: c#, java, oop

I am trying to do the design of a [Bejeweled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bejeweled) game. I have basically 3 classes. The `Game` class, which is what is going to be used by the player, a `Board` class, that represents the board, and a `SwitchController` class that is responsible for checking if the wanted switch on the board is valid, making the switch, counting the number of possible switches available (so I can know when the game is over, etc).

My current design is something like the following:

```
Game:
isGameOver()
isSwitchValid(coord1, coord2)
makeSwitch(coord1, coord2)
getPieceAt(coord)
getBoardLength()

IBoard:
getPieceAt(coord)
setPieceAt(coord, piece)
getLength()
```

My idea would then to have a `ISwitchController`:

```
ISwitchController:
isSwitchValid(coord1, coord2)
makeSwitch(coord1, coord2)
getAllValidSwitches()
```

Here is a little diagram of how the classes are to be organized:
[image]

I would have 2 different concrete classes of `IBoard` available for use (and for each one of them, I'd have to have an `ISwitchController` implementation).

### The problem:

My program is to have 2 IBoard implementations:

The first, `ArrayBoard`, will have all the pieces of the board stored in a 2D Array. There is nothing special about it. I will define an `ArrayBoardSwitchController` for managing this class.

The second, `ListBoard`, will have for each color of pieces, a List/Set with all the coordinates of the pieces of that color. I will define a `ListBoardSwitchController` for managing this class.

The main issue here is that the implementation of `SwitchController` will be totally different on `ArrayBoard` and on `ListBoard`. For example, while for implementing `getAllValidSwitches()` `ArrayBoardSwitchController` only needs the `getPieceAt()` method, that would not be a good idea to do with `ListBoardSwitchController`(in that class I use internally lists because it's easier to check if the move is valid that way).

From what I can see, there are 2 different possible solutions:

1. I could either merge together the
   `ISwitchController` and `IBoard`
   interfaces. That way I'd only have
   two classes, Game and Board (while
   basically Game would just be a
   controller for the Board, as it
   would be the Board that had all the
   game logic). It wouldn't be that nice
   because the classes wouldn't be
   as cohese as they could be if I had
   3 distinct classes.
2. Let the interfaces as they are and put
   all the methods I need to work with public
   in the concrete classes. For example, if I need
   a `getYellowPiecesList()` method, I'd put it public
   on `ListBoard` so `ListBoardSwitchController` could
   use it. `ListBoardSwitchController` would only
   know about it because it knows it only works
   against `ListBoards`.

What's your opinion on the matter? *The focus here is not so much on how to design the Bejeweled game, but how to solve this problem, that is recurrent when you try to implement algorithms: on one hand you want to have a clear and good OOP design, and in the other sometimes that gets in the way of having a sound and effective algorithm implementation.*

Comment: Unrelated: What software did you use to create that diagram?

Comment: @Adam: an inspection of the URL of the image reveals http://yuml.me/ as the root. It's an online UML diagramming tool, and something I've just bookmarked and intend to play with a lot.

Comment: @Randolpho - very cool, you can also purchase and download it :-)

Comment: @Adam: I found out about that site from a comment on Meta, and it's very cool. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The main issue here is that the implementation of SwitchController will be totally different on ArrayBoard and on ListBoard.

If this is the case, then it sounds like you haven't designed the `IBoard` interface well enough so that classes can use an implementation of `IBoard` without knowing the implementation details. If the user of an `IBoard` needs to know what implementation is being used, then it almost defeats the purpose of having an interface!

I would strongly suggest re-visiting the methods you are exposing on `IBoard` to see if there is a way you can expose something like "get the piece at this coordinate" in a more generic way. Make sure that any methods a controller needs to invoke on a `IBoard` instance are **only** the methods in the `IBoard` interface.

> For example, while for implementing getAllValidSwitches() ArrayBoardSwitchController only needs the getPieceAt() method, that would not be a good idea to do with ListBoardSwitchController(in that class I use internally lists because it's easier to check if the move is valid that way).

If an operation such as "get piece at this coordinate" is instrumental to the `IBoard` interface, then the implementations must be faithful to their contract and implement it correctly. It sounds as if your `ListBoard` is not faithfully meeting the contract set out in `IBoard`.

Comment: "If the user of an IBoard needs to know what implementation is being used, then it almost defeats the purpose of having an interface!" That is an excellent point. In relationship to your last point, currently both implementations implement the "get piece at this coordinate". The issue here is that for example, when wanting to know if a certain switch is valid with the List implementation, it wouldn't be a good idea to use the getPieceAt() method, as it would not take advantage of the implementation of that board.

Comment: Then I think that what you have is an argument that a List-based implementation is not a great idea, not an argument for using implementation-specific details directly. Perhaps, if there is another access pattern suitable for Lists, you can add that method to the interface as well (assuming that its an operation suitable for array-based implementations to implement as well).

Comment: The List based implementation is the FASTEST possible. That is the implementation I will want to use some day. But it can be quite complex, so I want to work right now with an array based one, to test everything up and only later have to fully implement the List based.

Comment: Right, but the regardless the purpose of an `interface` is to abstract away these details so that classes that use it only need to know what the allowed operations/methods are. Your task in designing an interface is to determine what operations a "Board" needs to have, regardless of how the data is stored.

Comment: I think I found a good working solution. I'll update the OP later with it.

Answer (score 3):

3: Let ArrayBoardSwitchController and ListBoardSwitchController be inner classes of ArrayBoard and ListBoard. The implementation of the controller is tied to the implementation of your board, thus it makes sense to keep them together. Because the controller will be an inner class you can use the implementation details from the board. Then to make it work extend the IBoard interface to return a ISwitchController.

Note that this is only slightly different from option 1. (The ISwitchController can now be used indirectly from a IBoard, merging them gives direct access to ISwitchController)

Comment: +1, though this does create a tighter coupling between the switch controller and the board than may actually be needed.  An alternate approach, if you wish to keep the  classes separate, is to define an additional interface, such as IListBoard, that the ListBoardSwitchController requires.  This is a slight variant on option (2) with reduced coupling.

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose of ListBoard as an object decoupled from ArrayBoard?  If I were going to bother with the list of gems at all, I would keep it in an object which also held an array of what was in each position, so that swapping the position of two gems could be done quickly and efficiently.  Not that I'm clear on why you need the position list anyhow?

If a 6507 running at 1.19Mhz with 128 bytes of RAM and 20% CPU availability can handle Columns, finding all 3-in-a-row combinations on a 6x20 in less than 100ms, I would think more modern machines could scan for moves acceptably fast without using a list of what gems are where.  I'd suggest padding your board array so you don't have to worry about edge cases, and for each gem check 16 combinations of various cells within 3 squares of it(*) to see if they both match it.  Some moves may be double-reported (e.g. this algorithm may detect that moving a gem left will create a 3-in-a-row, and also detect that moving the gem to the left of the first one right will create a 3-in-a-row) but that shouldn't be a problem.

(*) If a gem can move left, then it must match either the two gems to the left of the destination, or the two gems above the destination, or the two gems below, or one above and one below.  Likewise for the other directions.